# How to start a counter in cell A2 in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, counter

In Google Apps Script, I would like to initiate a counter starting from 1 onward, in cell A1 when the document is opened. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
function onOpen(e) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('NameOfTheSheet');
  const range = sheet.getRange('A1')
  range.setValue(range.getValue() + 1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I would like for the counter to keep increasing in numbers while the document is open in A1, not just stay at 1.

Comment: You mean like a timer?